# Can we have built 2 APK one for debug and other for test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, apk

I'm wondering if I can have 2 apk one normal apk that i built the package where I'm coding and other I wish I could with the test package

Comment: Yes you can build you app with different falvour . Check this out https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Answer (score 0):

While you can have a separate "test" [flavor](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html), it is not a very good approach.

Tests should run against the same code that will go into production. By having a separate "test" flavor, there will be a risk of divergence between "test" and "production" code.

Comment: okay i have 2 modules in one module i want to write all code and in the second module i want to write its tests so that i can have 2 apk one for normal code and other for test, is it possible that i can include package name of one module to other like i want to include package name of code classes into other module 's test classes

Comment: @blackHawk, in Android, we don't create separate modules for tests. Tests live in the same module as the code which is tested. Please read this: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html

Comment: Okay, can we make apk of package in android studio, because we can make apk of module